User can see a field that is not even inside the Page Layout
I have a custom object that a user accesses frequently.
Recently I received a report that this user was able to see too much fields, much more than usual.
I checked the permissions of this user. He has access to see the new fields because his profile is granting access to them
I checked the Page Layout assignments for the profile of this user, and I found that the field is not added anywhere in the page layout, for that particular profile and record type combination.
Then I checked the Lightning Record Page,to see if there was any Dynamic Forms added to the page. No Dynamic Forms are involved. Also I checked once and twice for any lightning component, and no one was involved either.
So I can confirm that all the fields in the record detail page come from the page layout
My question would be, how's it possible that a field is visible (in lighting experience) if it's not added inside the page layout? and the page layout is the only source for the fields to appear in screen.
My second question is how can this be fixed. Should I remove read permissions over the field?
Thank you!

Refer to this may help you. - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385112&type=1

I found the problem.
The user was accessing the record detail page from a custom app, and this app was assigned to see a different lightning record page, which also had dynamic forms.
So the problem was I didn't take into account the app assignments for lightning record pages.
